# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gdata.client.photos.PicasawebService

Tags: android, gdata, picasa

I´m using the Picasa Api and added the following libraries:

```
activation.jar
gdata-client-1.0.jar
gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar
gdata-core-1.0.jar
gdata-media-1.0.jar
gdata-photos-2.0.jar
gdata-photos-meta-2.0.jar
mail.jar
```

Further I´m importing:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.gdata.client.photos.PicasawebService;
import com.google.gdata.data.photos.AlbumFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.photos.PhotoEntry;

import com.google.gdata.client.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.photos.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.photos.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;
```

But at onCreate: `PicasawebService myPicasa = new PicasawebService("Test");` I get the following error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gdata.client.photos.PicasawebService`.

I´ve seen that other people have had the same issue, but I couldn´t find an answer for Android programming in Eclipse. Anybody any tips how to solve this? Why can´t it find the ClassDef?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that those jar files are not included in the built APK. You should create a `lib` folder inside your Android project folder and put the jars there and then reference them from the lib folder in your eclipse build path

Comment: I added them in configure buildpath -> Libraries -> Add Jars.. And I can see them now in referenced libraries, that should be it right? Cause it aint working.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you´re saying. Copy them into the lib and then add them to the build path, instead of directly adding them!

Comment: Also make sure the library is checked on the Order and Export tab on Configure Build Path screen.

Comment: I think it did it, only thing is now I get the following one: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.collect.Maps, but I´m gonna search on that one.

Comment: I found this solution on my last issue: I solved this problem by download the jar file guava-r07.jar. http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/downloads/detail?name=guava-r07.zip but it seems to be depreciated and I shouldn´t use it. Anybody know which JAR file I should use? And where I can download this one.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this library  http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list

for `PicasawebService`

Comment: I already downloaded the zip-file and used these files from that zip:  gdata-client-1.0.jar gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar gdata-core-1.0.jar gdata-media-1.0.jar gdata-photos-2.0.jar gdata-photos-meta-2.0.jar, do I need to do more?